# Elasticsearch 5.2 nested query for multi terms

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

nested document look like this

```
{
    "userid": "123",
    "usertag": [
        {
            "tag": "A",
            "logcreatetime": "2017-01-14"
        },
        {
            "tag": "C",
            "logcreatetime": "2017-01-17"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "userid": "456",
    "usertag": [
        {
            "tag": "A",
            "logcreatetime": "2017-01-12"
        },
        {
            "tag": "B",
            "logcreatetime": "2017-01-19"
        }
    ]
},
.....
```

usertag object is nested mapping,
how to get user id by 2017-01-12 to 2017-01-19 , has tag A and B?
thanks
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've indexed your `logcreatetime` as Date field, so you can use the following query:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_users/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ {
        "nested": {
          "path": "usertag",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "usertag.tag": "A" }},
                { "range" : {
                    "usertag.logcreatetime" : {
                      "gte": "2017-01-12",
                      "lte": "2017-01-19"
                    }
                }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "nested": {
          "path": "usertag",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "usertag.tag": "B" }},
                { "range" : {
                    "usertag.logcreatetime" : {
                      "gte": "2017-01-12",
                      "lte": "2017-01-19"
                    }
                }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}'
```

The limitation of syntax is that you can look for particular child which both has particular `tag` AND its `logcreatetime` lies within given range. But in order to ensure you'll have two children you should combine two nested queries into 2 must clauses of top-level `bool`.

Comment: thanks for you answer,but I'm sorry I did not make it clear。In fact i have more than two TAG in my query。Es do not have nested child query? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you can combine nested query and child query as these are using two different data structures. But what you can try to do is to make separation of concerns: store nested-related information separate from child-related. Is that the case for your scenario?

Comment: In fact, I need a certain period of time with some tag users. Then look at what other tags they have during this time. It seems difficult to draw this conclusion with ES. I have tried various data structures. The closest is the nested structure, but still looks or not.

Comment: Btw, how many fields do you have on parent-level? If there are not so many parent-fields and you don't have much use-cases for them - you could simply denormalize your data and make it flat, like `[{userid:123, usertag:a, time:xxx}, {userid:123, usertag:b, time:yyy}, {userid:456, usertag:c, time:zzz}, ...]`. Is that the case for your problem?